# Change language in iOS app

Tags: ios, multilingual

I display content in selected language which comes from the phone settings. Users may change the app language in settings of my app. I use NSUserDefaults to insert selected language to AppleLanguages key with setting objectAtIndex at 0. It works when application relaunches. But inside the app I cant see any change. I used NSUserDefaults syncronize but it is not working. 
Simply I want to reload my tabbed app views with chosen language at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, this isn't great user experience - languages are there to be set by the user for their personal aptitude. Your app is trying to forcibly dictate a language to them - behaviour that is at best frowned upon by Apple, and at worst will see your app rejected. I know Id definitely delete an app that tried to change one of my settings for me, especially a global one like preferred languages.

That being said, you can manipulate the localisation system by only supporting specific languages - you should never have to support that kind of requirement. Simply limit the supported languages to the ones you are prepared to offer translations for.

Lastly, Id expect that firstly you can't manipulate global settings like that as it breaks the application sandbox, and that secondly even if you could you'd have to find a way of relaunching your app anyway - itself a difficult proposition.

Comment: My app's localization supports two languages: turkish and english. Perhaps my way is wrong but what is the best? I have 1 localized storyboard that means one for turkish one for english.

Comment: Effectively you don't need to do any more work then - you simply need to put those as your supported localisations, and let the system do the rest.